# Empty Scope with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

Following Problem:
I need something like an empty scope. Which means that this scope is emtpy, but responds to all methods a scope usually responds to.
I'm currently using a little dirty hack. I simply supply "1=0" as conditions. I find this realy ugly, since it hits the database. Simply returning an empty array won't work, since the result must respond to the scoped methods.

Is there a better existing solution for this or will I need to code this myself?

Maybe some example code could help explain what i need:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :admins, :conditions => {:admin => true }
  named_scope :none_dirty, :conditions => "1=0" # this scope is always empty

  def none_broken
    []
  end

  def self.sum_score # okay, a bit simple, but a method like this should work!
    total = 0
    self.all.each do |user|
      total += user.score
    end
    return total
  end
end
User.admin.sum_score # the score i want to know
User.none_drity.sum_score # works, but hits the db
User.none_broken.sum_score # ...error, since it doesn't respond to sum_score
```

Comment: Why would the score of an empty set ever be anything other than 0? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: You are looking for an empty collection.

Comment: @jdl: it wouldn't be something other than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are looking for does not exist. You could implement something like this by monky patching the `find` method. Yet, this would be an overkill, so I recomend keeping this unless it's performance critical.

Answer (score 26):

Rails 4 introduces the `none` scope.

It is to be used in instances where you have a method which returns a relation, but there is a condition in which you do not want the database to be queried.

If you want a scope to return an unaltered scope use `all`:

No longer will a call to `Model.all` execute a query immediately and return an array of records. In Rails 4, calls to `Model.all` is equivalent to now deprecated `Model.scoped`. This means that more relations can be chained to `Model.all` and the result will be lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 11):

```
User.where('false')
```

returns an ActiveRecord::Relation with zero elements, that is a chain-able scope that won't hit the database until you actually try to access one of its elements. This is similar to PhilT's solution with ('1=0') but a little more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry `User.scoped` is not what you want. As commented this returns everything. Should have paid more attention to the question.

I've seen `where('1 = 0')` suggested before and Rails should probably cache it as well.

Also, `where('1 = 0')` won't hit the database until you do `.all`, `.each`, or one of the calculations methods.

Comment: `User.scoped` returns all users, so it's not really an "empty" scope.  I think he means an empty scope that would return no users.  Sort of equivalent to [] but a scope.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need `User.scoped({})`

Comment: Wouldn't `User.scoped({})` be equivalent to `User.all`?

Comment: @Swanand: they are not equivalent, `scoped` returns a lazy `ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope` while `User.all` returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

How about `User.where(id: nil)` ?

Or `User.where(_id: nil)` for mongoid.

Comment: That will still hit the database and it's not reliable (It's possible to have a record with a null id field especially legacy, non Rails databases).

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your example code indicates you may not know about aggregated queries in SQL which are exposed as calculations methods in Rails:

`User.sum(:score)` will give you the sum of all users' scores

Take a look at Rails Guides for more info:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#sum

Comment: Ehm, no, the sum was just an example as stated above