# Rails: how to make class method scope to handle nil arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I started using class method scopes because I need to pass some argument into the scope. Taking the Rails Guide example:

```
  def self.1_week_before(time)
    where("created_at < ?", time)
  end
```

However in my site sometimes the argument can be nil, in that case I want to bypass that scoping and go to the next scope in the chain.

I added the if condition in the method:

```
  def self.1_week_before(time)
    if time
      where("created_at < ?", time)
    end
  end
```

However when I use this method in the middle of scope chaining, it will gives undefined method for nil:NilClass error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns `nil`, so you get the error when you chain:

```
def self.1_week_before(time)
  if time
    where("created_at < ?", time)
  end
end
```

To prevent this you could return `scoped`:

```
def self.1_week_before(time)
  if time
    where("created_at < ?", time)
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

Comment: I just found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735838/empty-scope-with-ruby-on-rails) that `scoped` should be better than `all`. Can you change it and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out... I learned something myself :-)